# How to add the img-responsive class in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to make a responsive slider for mobile version. 
Site was developed using angular JS.
When I am trying to integrate the JQuery sliders, total site was distubing because of Bootstrap CSS file. 
So, in that part I founded a plain Javascript code. And in this how to make those images responsive.
Below I am adding the code.

```
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var slideimages = new Array() // create new array to preload images
    slideimages[0] = new Image() // create new instance of image object
    slideimages[0].src = "images/slide/1.jpg" // set image object src property to an image's src, preloading that image in the process
    slideimages[1] = new Image()
    slideimages[1].src = "images/slide/2.jpg"
    slideimages[2] = new Image()
    slideimages[2].src = "images/slide/2.jpg"
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <a href="javascript:slidelink()"><img src="firstcar.gif" id="slide" width=100 height=56 /></a>

<script type="text/javascript">

//variable that will increment through the images
var step = 0
var whichimage = 0

function slideit(){
 //if browser does not support the image object, exit.
 if (!document.images)
  return
 document.getElementById('slide').src = slideimages[step].src
 whichimage = step
 if (step<2)
  step++
 else
  step=0
 //call function "slideit()" every 2.5 seconds
 setTimeout("slideit()",2500)
}

function slidelink(){
 if (whichimage == 0)
  window.location = "#"
 else if (whichimage == 1)
  window.location = "#"
 else if (whichimage == 2)
  window.location = "#"
}

slideit()

</script>
```

Comment: `document.location = "https://www.google.nl/webhp?tab=ww&ei=d8p5VPSTLMfkUpf7gpgE&ved=0CAkQ1S4#safe=off&q=How+to+add+a+class+in+javascript"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previous answers are correct but you have to use $ for jQuery:

```
$(slideimages[0]).addClass("img-responsive");
```

WIthout jQuery:

```
slideimages[0].className += "img-responsive";
```

Comment: then just:

slideimages[0].className += "img-responsive";

Comment: But sliding the images was not getting.. Dont know why.. Script is fine.. But images not sliding.. Here is the link http://m.instylenewyork.com/index.html#/  . . .Can u plz help me out from it.. Thank

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to do but you can start by fixing the javascript errors, if you take a look to your browser's console, there are some script errors and not found files, the first script is giving you an error because you are using $ jQuery before the library is loaded, try to wrap that with window.onload event or jQuery's equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

To add a class, just use addClass:

```
slideimages[0].addClass("img-responsive");
```

Are you just trying to add a class? I don't quite understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED** you simply need to do this:

```
function slideit(){
 //if browser does not support the image object, exit.
 if (!document.images)
  return
 document.getElementById('slide').src = slideimages[step].src
document.getElementById('slide').className = "img-responsive";
 whichimage = step
 if (step<2)
  step++
 else
  step=0
 //call function "slideit()" every 2.5 seconds
 setTimeout("slideit()",2500)
}
```

Comment: @D.M. Vamsi change your slideit() method with this and try.

Comment: No use.. Not effecting.