# JQuery not adding class to child images of parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I feel a little bit ashamed about this, but I am having a lot of trouble getting Jquery to select my article body, grab the children images and add classes to it.
I've tried replacing `card` with `post-body` and `card-body` but no luck either.

I just started learning jq.

I searched stack overflow and I believe I am using the css selector correctly.

[addClass to body won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35365644/addclass-to-body-wont-work)

[How to add a class to body tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283511/how-to-add-a-class-to-body-tag)

[How to add the img-responsive class in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27202749/how-to-add-the-img-responsive-class-in-javascript)

I am pretty sure I am doing it correctly (despite it not working for some reason), but I am not sure where the problem could be.

Base HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    ...
    {% load static %}

    {% block js %}
    {% endblock %}
    ...
</head>
```

Post Detail Template:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block js %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/post-detail.js' %}"></script>

{% endblock %}

  <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body post-body">

                 // image added here in admin by using 'ckeditor'
                 <img alt="" src="..." style="height:792px; width:1280px">  

            </div>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('card').children('img').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass('d-block img-fluid mx-auto');
  });
});
```

I do not understand why it's not selecting the image tags and adding the class to it. Any ideas?

edit: In case you have similar trouble, if you check the browser's console log you might see `ReferenceError: "x" is not defined`. Make sure you load jq first.

Comment: `$('card')` is looking for `<card>`.  A typo i assume.

Comment: Also `.children()` just looks for *immediate* children. You need `.find()`.

Comment: try `$('card')`  to `$('.card')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple issues.  First, your selector is doing `$('card')` which is trying to find a `<card>` element, which does not exist.  Since it's a class, you want to use `$('.card')`.

Secondly, the images are not direct children of the card.  They are nested two levels deep, so `children()` will not work.  You can use `find()` to fix this.

However, your code could be fixed and reduced at the same time.

```
$('.card img').addClass('d-block img-fluid mx-auto');`
```

There is no need to write the explicit each.  jQuery will automatically loop over every result in it's stack when you perform a method like addClass.

Comment: Oddly enough I did try that in the beginning, before I started just guessing and getting creative with the code. I did figure out that I wasn't loading the library though :(

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `$('.card img').each(......`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.card img').each(function(el){
    $(this).addClass('d-block img-fluid mx-auto');
    // Only for demonstration
    console.log('Class added: ' + $(this).attr('class'));
  });
});
```

```css
img{
   max-height: 100px;
   max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body post-body">

       // image added here in admin by using 'ckeditor'
       <img alt="" src="https://www.istockphoto.com/resources/images/PhotoFTLP/img_67920257.jpg" style="height:792px; width:1280px"/>  

  </div>
</div>
```